# How to read data from a html text box, and print(echo) the data in php in the same format as in the text box?

Tags: php, html

I am beginner to PHP and here is my question.
I have a text box and a 'Print' button. If 'Print' button is clicked, it should display the list of names entered in the text box. I'd written the following code, but the problem is, if I click the 'Print' button, it shows the names in a single line, instead of showing names in line by line format. Can someone help me in this. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Form Page</title>    
</head>
<body>

<form action="Files.php" method="get">
<textarea rows="15" cols="30" value="textbox" name="textbox"></textarea></br>
<input type="submit" value="Print" name="Print">
</form>

</body>
</html>

<?php
if(isset($_GET['Print'])){
    $file_print = $_GET["textbox"];
    echo $file_print;
}
?>
```

Comment: Simplest would be to use `<pre>`-tags around the output. That makes line breaks work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`nl2br()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) in PHP

Replace `echo $file_print;` with `echo nl2br($file_print);`

#### For edit..

```
echo nl2br($file_print);
file_put_contents('names.txt',$file_print,FILE_APPEND); //<-- Remove FILE_APPEND if you want to overwrite the file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Shankar Damodaran! The command works fine :) Also i need one more help... can i able to save the same format entered in text box to a text file?

Comment: Yes just add `file_put_contents('names.txt',$file_print);` below that line.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link Poomrokc!

Comment: Thanks a lot Shankar Damodaran!!, the file_put_contents works fine :)

Comment: @Latchu, Your welcome mate. Your paintings are amazing ! Keep up !

Answer (score 1):

Use `nl2br()`

`nl2br` — Inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string.

So in your case, you need to do this `echo nl2br($file_print);`

Comment: Thanks Mittul Chauhan!